# How do I register a PayPal IPN listener URL in WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress, paypal

**Context:** I'm migrating a bunch of subscription products from WooCommerce Subscriptions over to Easy Digital Downloads Recurring Payments.

**The Problem:** While I am able to map all of the fields correctly and migrate them from WooCommerce into Easy Digital Downloads, I am unable to get EDD to listen for and properly respond to the Instant Payment Notifications from PayPal. This is happening for 2 reasons:

1. The IPN URL for each subscription was set to the WooCommerce IPN listener url (/wc-api/WC_Gateway_Paypal/).
2. The "Custom" field was set to an array containing information about the WooCommerce subscription and order. EDD looks for a string containing it's internal payment ID.

So to make this work, I want to create an IPN listener at the WooCommerce endpoint and then right my own functions that will find the correct subscription and payments in EDD in update them accordingly.

I know how to write all the functions to process the IPN, but I don't know how to register that URL so that when the IPN hits it, all of the POST information is dumped into my function.

So I'm looking for something that will allow me to establish that URL on my site to work as the IPN listener. This is fictitious code, but it should serve to demonstrate what I'm hoping to accomplish:

```
register_URL('/wc-api/WC_Gateway_Paypal/' , 'my_custom_function' );
my_custom_function() {
    $ipn_data = $_POST;
    // Process the data
}
```

So essentially, anytime that URL gets hit, it activates my function which will then process it all.

**Update:** I've now achieved half of what I'm trying to achieve. I have now established that URL as valid URL that I can load on the site. However, instead of running my function, it's showing a list of blog posts (essentially loading an archive.php or something). What I need is for this URL to ONLY run my function and nothing else. Here's what I have so far:

```
// Add query vars.
add_filter( 'query_vars' , 'swp_add_api_query_vars' , 10 );
function swp_add_api_query_vars( $vars ) {
    $vars[] = 'wc-api';
    return $vars;
}

// Register API endpoints.
add_action( 'init' , 'swp_add_endpoint' , 0 );
function swp_add_endpoint() {
    add_rewrite_endpoint( 'wc-api', EP_PERMALINK );
}

add_action( 'parse_request' , 'swp_handle_api_requests' , 0 );
function swp_handle_api_requests() {

    global $wp;

    if ( ! empty( $_GET['wc-api'] ) ) {
        $wp->query_vars['wc-api'] = $_GET['wc-api'];

        echo 'test';

    }

}
```

The desired outcome is that the URL doesn't load any content but rather only triggers that handler function at the bottom of the code.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into the valid-paypal-standard-ipn-request hook?  http://codecharismatic.com/run-your-own-damn-code-after-paypal-calls-woocommerce-back/

```
add_action( 'valid-paypal-standard-ipn-request', 'handle_paypal_ipn_response', 10, 1 );

function handle_paypal_ipn_response( $formdata ) {

    if ( !empty( $formdata['invoice'] ) && !empty( $formdata['custom'] ) ) {

        if( $formdata['payment_status'] == 'Completed' ) {

            // unserialize data
            $order_data = unserialize( str_replace('\"', '"', $formdata['custom'] ) );

            // get order
            $order_id = $order_data[0];
            $order = new WC_Order( $order_id );

            // got something to work with?
            if ( $order ) {

                // get user id
                $user_id = get_post_meta( $order_id, '_customer_user', true );

                // get user data
                $user = get_userdata( $user_id );

                // get order items
                $items = $order->get_items();

                // loop thru each item
                foreach( $items as $order_item_id => $item ) {

                    $product = new WC_Product( $item['product_id'] );

                    // do extra work...

                }   
            }   
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: 1. We are migrating away from WooCommerce so most of those hooks and functions included in your answer won't be available for use. 2. This doesn't address the issue of creating an endpoint URL that allows me to trigger my function when it's pinged. I believe I may be onto something here with the WP API by creating an endpoint: http://v2.wp-api.org/extending/adding/

Comment: If WooCommerce is going away entirely then you could just setup your own IPN listener at that URL and do whatever you need to do with it.

Comment: That's literally what I'm asking how to do. How do I set it in WordPress so that when that URL is reached it triggers my function to process it. I'm not worried about the function, just making the URL trigger the function.

Comment: If WC is gone completely then yourdomain.com/wc-api/WC_Gateway_Paypal/ would return a 404.  So then  you just create a /wc-api/WC_Gateway_Paypal/ folder in your site structure and it would run directly...outside of WordPress.

Comment: I've added newly discovered information to the initial question above. Yes, it does return a 404 when it's gone, but using some add_query_vars, I've been able to add it back. Now I just need to get that URL to trigger my function. It's imperative that it live inside of WordPress rather than a standalone script because I need to be able to access WP functions as well as EDD function.